# Custom credential provider for *additional* authentication factor?

Tags: credential-providers

When a user wants to login to a windows workstation, he should enter his usual credentials, but if some condition is met, he should also be asked for another, secondary code.

Is it possible to write a custom credential provider to just add this secondary password, or do I have to replace the system credential provider(s) completely?

I've read everything I could find about credential providers, but don't see a good way to do this. Microsoft says, wrapping a system credential provider is something to [avoid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/credential-providers-in-windows#wrapping-credential-providers), because it could break on next Windows update.

But, replacing it instead would mean I have to do the complete authentication including the normal password. And it would also mean I have to disable the original system credential provider, which is again [not recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/credential-providers-in-windows#system-credential-providers).

So, what's a good way to do it? And are there any good examples, I could extend? C# preferred, but not required.

Comment: You may have a look at `SampleWrapExistingCredentialProvider` from Microsoft's examples. There you have a chance to add or remove any fields and control their behaviour.

Comment: Have a look at [pGina](https://github.com/pgina/pgina/wiki) project.

Comment: Thanks, I found pGina already yesterday, but didn't see a way to "chain" 2 different credentials, so they are both required. I'll look through it again. Any more specific hints appreciated...

Comment: I have already implemented 3 credential providers. One of them is for Two-Factor Logon to Windows using hardware tokens and their PIN-codes. In my case the only accessible for user field is "password type" edit for entering PIN-code. As a result my CP serialize user's credentials (domain, login, password). Everything works fine for a years.

Comment: That sounds great, @Alexander. So you used the WrapExisting approach despite all the warnings about beeing locked out after next windows update? Or is your suggestion disabling the system credential provider and replacing it by my own one (or pGina), which then asks for both credential types? Both approaches don't feel elegant to me :)

Comment: No, I not using Wrap provider, not disabling system ones. I just implemented my own provider that so server based check of user factors and as a result serialize users credential. I have build my CP on basis of `SampleAllControlsCredentialProvider` and `SampleHardwareEventCredentialProvider` examples. My suggestion to use `SampleWrapExistingCredentialProvider` and `pGina` is based on my experience of implementing own tons of related stuff.

Comment: Because of the warnings regarding breaking changes in future Windows updates, I don't like to try the WrapExisting approach. So it seems it is necessary to write a new credential provider which checks both the normal password and that new additional (otp) code. I don't really like that and still hope for better ideas.
I also investigated pGina extensively (there is a newer fork http://mutonufoai.github.io/pgina/), some things are nice, others not, i.e. I don't want to install a service.

Comment: If you do not want to wrap the existing credential provider, you will need to serialise the password in addition to verifying your additional factor, in the `GetSerialization` method. Code for this can be found in the pGina project. You will also have to specify which authentication package to use, although this can be determined by a call to `LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage`